# How to use OpenJSSE with maven?

Tags: java, maven, https, tls1.3

I am writing programmes in Java 8. (May upgrade to Java 11 later).
The programmes are basically two servers, with APIs talk with each others.

Since I would like to use the TLS1.3 protocol, I found OpenJSSE may be a good choice for me (which support TLS1.3 for Java 8.) However, after I added the dependency of OpenJSSE 1.1.4, I don't know what to do...

I know it sounds stupid, but I hardly found any tutorial about the library. *(apart from "-XX:+UseOpenJSSE")*

For example, I would like to use *ChaCha20KeyGenerator*, but it is a *final* class with *protected* methods. I just cannot call them successfully. Or I am using it completely wrong?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u261-relnotes.html ?

Comment: Just an advice - if you are planning to upgrade to 11, start writing with 11 right away. Migrating ready applications to 11 is a pain.

Comment: @khmarbaise oh... I don't know that TLS1.3 had come to Java 8 already! Thank you so much for your information :') But sadly I am not the one who has the final say, so I cannot upgrade to 8u261 or 11 now...

Am I getting it right: No matter the Java or the library (In fact it just reduplicates Java 11 codes, I think), I cannot use the encryption/decryption alone without TLS connection?

Comment: @JAsgarov I think the syntax is pretty much the same? My boss said we "may" switch to Java 11 after the programmes are finished (like as an upgrade LOL)

Comment: lol it is not the syntax it is the modules, plugins, different kind of dependencies. Starting with 11 is no problem, migrating is messier than divorce after 3 kids.

Comment: @JAsgarov Yes, my boss said due to time limit, she doesn't want we to spend time on finding new libraries or plugins... tbh, I think the chance of "upgrading" is very slim